# Does running large file compression on SSD go faster than on HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, processing

Let's say I have 5000 images I need to compress.

Option A.

Source folder on SSD and destination folder on HDD (Sata)

Option B.

Source folder on SSD and destination folder on SSD

Option C.

Source folder on HDD and destination folder on HDD

Will they all process the data at the same speed or option B. will be the fastest, and will it be a big difference?

Comment: There is no cut and dried answer to this question since it would depend on the actual equipment involved. A slow SSD and a fast HDD may actually be fairly comparable. One other consideration is the controller being used. I would expect that two fast SSD drives (something like a Samsung 950 Pro) with one for reading and one for writing would be fastest. See http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/best-ssds,3891.html However since you are doing compression, processor speed and capabilities would be crucial as well as the compression algorithm being used.

Comment: What kind of compression do you want to use? jpg?

Answer (score 1):

1. SSD to SSD will be fastest.
2. HDD to SSD will be usually be second - hdd reads are faster then writes but if you are compressing to more then about 5 times the reverse may be true (exact ratio depends on speeds of devices. I assume HDD is 100mbit, SSD is 500 mbit. YMMV
3. SSD to/from HDD will be faster then HDD to HDD

The relative differences will depend on the speed of compression - if it's heavily CPU bound the differences will be less noticeable then speed optimised compression